# Why does Akka not return address/host info?

Tags: akka, akka-remote-actor, akka-remoting

Akka 2.5 here. I have a need to determine if a particular `ActorRef` is located on the same JVM as my application. My best attempt:

```
someActor.path().address().host().isEmpty()
```

...is returning `true` for me (its empty; no address/host info available). Again, all I'm trying to do is determine if `someActor` (which is an `ActorRef`) is: (a) running inside the application JVM or (b) if it's a remote actor living inside another JVM and communicating w/ my app via akka-aremote.

Is there a better way to do this? Do I need to configure something inside `application.conf` for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is the proper way of doing it.

I suggest to send a message to target actor requesting current location and have the target actor respond back with hostname or address when you can compare and see.

Comment: Thanks @Gajendra (+1), so you recommend just using something like `InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost()` right from inside the actors and using that instead?

Comment: No. You may need to use system.provider.getDefaultAddress